# RSS feed is downloading

Tags: feeds

I just noticed today that my rss feed is not working properly. When I click it, it prompts me to download it.

My site is http://www.sourcecodester.com/

The rss feed url is: http://www.sourcecodester.com/feed

Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: There is a validation issue that may keep your default RSS handler from responding properly. The feed works fine in my feed reader though. http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sourcecodester.com%2Ffeed

Answer (score 1):

I can see one empty line in beginning. This might be due to a empty line in any one of your modules. In PHP blank lines before `<?php` tag causes a lot of problems remove it and check again. have a look at other site [XML](http://drupal.org/rss.xml) (Source Code) for proper format.

Comment: hi, i really don't know where to edit that. can you please guide me? thanks

Comment: Check all of your .module files. At the beginning of file there should not be any empty lines before opening `<?php` tag. This will send incorrect headers and might cause sessions to fail as well.

Comment: it appears that there's a space at the very top of the page before `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">`. do you have any idea where to remove this line feed? i already check html.tpl.php but there's no space at the top of the code.

Comment: That space will be there on all pages. Look in your `.module` files under sites/all/modules or sites/default/modules. Check all files for a blank line at beginning of file

Comment: i open all the .module file but can't find any space at the top of every code. any other posible locaton?

Comment: View it in firefox? Chrome will download but firefox will format and display it out of the box.